# Loading views from NIB to use as pages in a scrollview cancels autolayout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, nib

I've searched this issue, but did not managed to find a working answer.
I need to show a paging scrollview that shows some views loaded from .xib files, here's my code:

This is the init code for TutorialPage.m, subclass of UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPage:(int) page
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
     NSLog(@"tutorial page %d initialized", page);
    switch (page) {
        case 0:
            self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TutorialPage01View" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TutorialPage02View" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSLog(@"frame %g %g, %g %g", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    [self addSubview:self.view];

}



return self;
}
```

The pages are added to the scrollview as follows, the code below is part of TutorialViewController.m, that has a valid scrollview outlet:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

NSLog(@"tutorial view loaded");

self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[TutorialPage01 alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPage:i];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

}

}
```

The layouts are divided in two halves, vertically. And each half has constraints to make it match the container view and have equal heights.

**THE PROBLEM IS**

When the views are added to the scrollview they kinda ignore the autolayout, and the subview that should have a size of (290, 538), presents itself as (320,568), so it invades the other pages.

Is it possible to add constraints in the .xib file and then have then applied to the superview it is added, in code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way to do it. Since you're adding a new frame programmatically, you should also ensure that the view you are replacing conforms to the frame you are initiating.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPage:(int) page
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TutorialView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        view.frame = self.frame;
        [self addSubview:view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This seemed to work for me in a much simpler app I built based on your code.